# SQL: Repeating data in JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing homework for my class and I can't figure out how to properly answer this question:

"Determine which books generate less than a 55% profit and how many copies of these books have been sold. Summarize your findings for management, and include a copy of the query used to retrieve data from the database tables."

I tried taking a shot at it but I can't seem to get it to come out the way I want it to. It always has data that doesn't seem to go together. Below is my code:

```
SELECT isbn, b.title, b.cost, b.retail, o.quantity "# of times Ordered",
   ROUND(((retail-cost)/retail)*100,1)||'%' "Percent Profit", 
   o.quantity "# of times Ordered"
FROM books o JOIN orderitems o USING(isbn);
```

It works in the sense that I get the data I need but it comes up like this:

[image]

I have a theory that because the table "Order Items" has multiple orders with the same isbn and different quantities it's selecting all of them. Is there a way to combine them? If not could anyone help me get rid of the redundant data caused by the JOIN?

Thank you!

Comment: You've tagged this with `mysql` and `sql-server` yet in your question, your using `oracle`. Please tag your question properly.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for `books` and `orderitems` and expected result?

Comment: You can SUM retail and cost... then group by ISBN.. hope this helps you!.

Comment: Why do both tables in your query have the same alias (`o`)? EDIT: looks like a typo, as you are using `b` elsewhere. Please try to make sure the code you put in the question matches what you are using, or we might be debugging the wrong thing.

Comment: Before you INNER JOIN your tables.. select first the result that you needed in the first and second table.. after getting the result in both table you can now inner join.. I'm not familiar with the syntax of oracle... but in MYSQL you can do something like this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * blah2) table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * blah2) table2 ON table1.id = table2.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do similar things in SQL Server / MySQL. You need to group by the columns in which you see repeated data that you do not care about, and you need to SUM the field whose values are important to you, probably something like this...

```
SELECT isbn, b.title, b.cost, b.retail, o.quantity "# of times Ordered",
   ROUND(((retail-cost)/retail)*100,1)||'%' "Percent Profit", 
   SUM(o.quantity) "# of times Ordered"
FROM books o JOIN orderitems o USING(isbn)
GROUP BY isbn, b.title, b.cost, b.retail;
```

If you need more information, go here and search for SUM: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html

Answer (score 0):

You are focusing on books, so you need to group this query on `isbn`, `b.title`, `b.cost`, `b.retail` and `ROUND(((retail-cost)/retail)*100,1)`.

You should `SUM(o.quantity)` to get a total number of copies sold for each book.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT title, sum(quantity),Round(((retail-cost)/retail)*100, 0) Percent_Profit
FROM books NATURAL JOIN orderitems group by title, cost, retail;

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted (see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), has not explanation on why it should work and there is already an answer that does all that and is accepted. Please only write an answer in such a case if you have valuable info to add (maybe if a new version of something got released with new features).